# Parent and Child Total in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for the accumulation of total of Child in to parent

Although I am able to get the child total can anyone assist for the same below is the

| CODE | PARENT CHLD | TERM_LOAN_TOTAL1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40100 | : AGRICULTURE | Required values 11565000 |
|  | 40110 : Crop Production |  |
|  | 40120 : Poultry and livestock | 11565000 |
|  | 40130 : Fishing |  |
|  | 40140 : Plantation |  |
|  | 40150 : Agro Services |  |
|  | 40160 : Cash Crop |  |
| 40200 | : MINING AND QUARRYING |  |

This is my SQL query:

```sql
select cdd, prnt, chld, term_loan_total1
 from (SELECT x.mis_code cdd,
               CASE
                 WHEN x.mis_code LIKE '%00' THEN
                  to_char(lpad(nvl(x.mis_code, 0), 5, ':') || '   :  ' ||
                          x.code_desc)
               END prnt,
               CASE
                 WHEN x.mis_code NOT LIKE '%00' THEN
                  to_char(lpad(nvl(x.mis_code, 0), 5, ':') || '   :  ' ||
                          x.code_desc)
               END chld,
               
               (select sum(ct.amount_disbursed)
                  from cltb_account_master ct
                  left join mitm_customer_default mic
                    on ct.customer_id = mic.customer
                  left join gltm_mis_code msc
                    on mic.cust_mis_2 = msc.mis_code
                 where ct.product_code not in ('SBAD')
                   and msc.mis_code = x.mis_code) term_loan_total1
           FROM gltm_mis_code x
         WHERE mis_class in ('CBN_SUBS', 'CBN_SECT')
         group by x.mis_code, x.code_desc
         order by x.mis_code)
 group by cdd, prnt, chld, term_loan_total1
 order by cdd
```

Attached the CRUD script for two tables

```
-- Create table
create table CLTTBL
(
  account_number   VARCHAR2(35),
  amount_disbursed NUMBER
)
tablespace test
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
  
  
  prompt Importing table clttbl...
set feedback off
set define off
insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390016', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221500006', 85000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221430007', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390011', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390012', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221500003', 80000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221430004', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390003', 10000000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221430003', 80000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390010', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390019', 85000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221430002', 50000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221400002', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390004', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390017', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221390018', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221430006', 100000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('001SBTL221400001', 85000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('000SBTL222130004', 10000000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('000SBTL221390001', 5000000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('000SBTL221390003', 10000000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('000SBTL221390007', 10000000);

insert into clttbl (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, AMOUNT_DISBURSED)
values ('000SBTL222130003', 5000000);

prompt Done.
```

MIS table insert

```
create table gltm_mis_cd
(
  PRNT   VARCHAR2(35),
  CHLD VARCHAR2(35),
  CODE_DESC VARCHAR2(35),
)
tablespace test
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );


prompt Importing table gltm_mis_cd...
set feedback off
set define off
insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values ('40100   :  AGRICULTURE', null, 'AGRICULTURE');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40110   :  Crop Production', 'Crop Production');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40120   :  Poultry and livestock', 'Poultry and livestock');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40130   :  Fishing', 'Fishing');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40140   :  Plantation', 'Plantation');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40150   :  Agro Services', 'Agro Services');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40160   :  Cash Crop', 'Cash Crop');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values ('40200   :  MINING AND QUARRYING', null, 'MINING AND QUARRYING');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40210   :  Metal: Tin, Iron, etc', 'Metal: Tin, Iron, etc');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40220   :  Non-metal Quarrying', 'Non-metal Quarrying');

insert into gltm_mis_cd (PRNT, CHLD, CODE_DESC)
values (null, '40230   :  Others', 'Others');
```

Prompt done.

[parent Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkH4v.png)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for the sample data that generates your output; a detailed explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: I totally agree with your advice  but some table in the SQL  , are huge in data and extracting data  structure are big in nature these are the  Limitation  facing the request stated above 
Thank you  for the advice  But will put the effort in  extracting the same
Regards

Comment: That is why I said a [MRE] - the emphasis is on minimal - you can strip out all the unnecessary columns from the tables and only include a few rows of data. If you cannot give us a way of replicating the problem then how do you expect us to be able to answer the question?

Comment: Sure Sir , I can understand the requirement 
I am ready to  provide remote to my data base , if any one would tike particiapate in remote  
I can provide the Ultraviewer access 
let me know there personal mail ID I will contact personally through mail

Comment: Do **NOT** do that (it is potentially a huge security issue for your database, and you are also implicitly requesting other user's emails). Just make the effort to provide a [MRE] in your question.

Comment: Noted  i am   working on getting the inc/dll  script

Comment: Provided the CRUD   statement for Table create and  insert script   Let me know   in case any further  details needed

Comment: we are missing some of the tables from your SQL,. so we can't link the two you've provided

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things missing in this question to give the excat answer, but maybe (with all your other tables and links between them) you just need thhe CASE expression to solve the problem. Below is just an example of one of many ways you could use it.
More about CASE expression with examples at https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/
To get your job done you should add your own tables and joins as well as adjust the WHERE, GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause. The most important is to write your own CASE expression. In this example I use fixed values because there are not sample data from your other tables. Hope you could get a little push in right direction by this...

```sql
Select
    SubStr(Nvl(g.PRNT, g.CHLD), 1, 5) "CDD",
    g.PRNT "PRNT",
    g.CHLD "CHLD",
    Sum(CASE WHEN Nvl(SubStr(g.CHLD, 1, 5), '40120') = '40120' THEN c.AMOUNT_DISBURSED END) "TERM_LOAN_TOTAL_1"
From
    GLTM_MIS_CD g
Inner Join
    CLTTBL c ON(1=1 And SubStr(c.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 1, 3) = '001')
Where
    SubStr(Nvl(g.PRNT, g.CHLD), 1, 3) = '401'
Group By
    SubStr(Nvl(g.PRNT, g.CHLD), 1, 5),
    g.PRNT,
    g.CHLD
Order By
    SubStr(Nvl(g.PRNT, g.CHLD), 1, 5)
```

Result

| CDD | PRNT | CHLD | TERM_LOAN_TOTAL_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40100 | 40100 : AGRICULTURE |  | 11565000 |
| 40110 |  | 40110 : Crop Production |  |
| 40120 |  | 40120 : Poultry and livestock | 11565000 |
| 40130 |  | 40130 : Fishing |  |
| 40140 |  | 40140 : Plantation |  |
| 40150 |  | 40150 : Agro Services |  |
| 40160 |  | 40160 : Cash Crop |  |

Regards...